# bind database value in html input type textbox in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to know that how to bind value in html text box in mvc from database.

i am using datepicker in that input type textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="objmember.BirthDate" data-beatpicker="true" class="span4" />
```

i am able to submit the value from this textbox in database field but while edit it i need to already show the date in this input type text box.on the other hand other textbox are showing the value fine.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.objmember.Name, new { placeholder = "Name", @class = "span4" })
```

i am using viewModel in this view.but writing `name="objmember.BirthDate"` is not binding the value with this textbox.

above default `textbox` of `mvc` works fine with it.but on using input type text it is not binding the value. i have to use this datepicker in input type field because it is not working with `@Html.Textbox`.

Please give me some solution to this problem.

Comment: i already tried this but it gives error -CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: may be possible using mvc display template and UIHint

Comment: That's odd. Can you try to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.objmember.BirthDate, new { placeholder = "BirthDate", @class = "span4", new { data_beatpicker = "true" })`